# Problem with last version of font awesome in moderncv

Tags: xetex, compiling, moderncv, fontawesome

After updating `fontawesome` package I can't comile my moderncv-document.

It works without `\moderncvicons{awesome}`.

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}


\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resum\`e title} 
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}   
\homepage{www.johndoe.com} 
\social[linkedin]{john.doe} 
\social[twitter]{jdoe}      
\social[github]{jdoe}       

\moderncvicons{awesome}


\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
  \begin{itemize}%
  \item Sub-achievement (a);
  \item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Sub-sub-achievement i;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
    \end{itemize}
  \item Sub-achievement (c);
  \end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: FYI, "resumé" has an acute accent: `resum\'e` (or `resume`, or `r\'esum\'e`) is the correct `LaTeX`. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following restores the missing `\faLinkedInSign` and `\faCircleBlank` required under XeLaTeX (taken from [Revision 29485](http://tug.org/svn/texlive/trunk/Master/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontawesome/fontawesome.sty?view=markup&pathrev=29485) of `moderncv`):

[image]

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\name{John}{Doe}
\title{Resum\'e title} 
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}   
\homepage{www.johndoe.com} 
\social[linkedin]{john.doe} 
\social[twitter]{jdoe}      
\social[github]{jdoe}       

\moderncvicons{awesome}

%\renewcommand*{\addresssymbol}       {}
\renewcommand*{\mobilephonesymbol}   {{\Large\faMobilePhone}~~}
\renewcommand*{\fixedphonesymbol}    {\faPhone~~}
\renewcommand*{\faxphonesymbol}      {\faPrint~~}              % alternative: \faFileAlt
\renewcommand*{\emailsymbol}         {\faEnvelope~~}           % alternative: \faInbox
\renewcommand*{\homepagesymbol}      {\faGlobe~~}              % alternative: \faHome
\renewcommand*{\linkedinsocialsymbol}{\faLinkedinSign~~}       % alternative: \faLinkedin
\renewcommand*{\twittersocialsymbol} {\faTwitter~~}
\renewcommand*{\githubsocialsymbol}  {\faGithub~~}

\def\faLinkedinSign{{\FA\symbol{"F08C}}}
\def\faCircleBlank{{\FA\symbol{"F10C}}}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\FA}{%
  \fontencoding{EU1}\fontfamily{FontAwesome(0)}\fontsize{5}{5}\selectfont}

\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:
\begin{itemize}%
  \item Achievement 1;
  \item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
    \begin{itemize}%
      \item Sub-achievement (a);
      \item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
        \begin{itemize}
        \item Sub-sub-achievement i;
        \item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
        \item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
        \end{itemize}
      \item Sub-achievement (c);
    \end{itemize}
  \item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}}

\end{document}
```

Additionally I've added some more spaces after the symbols so that they don't seem as close to the tombstone information.

A forced `\fontsize{5}{5}` for using the FontAwesome fonts (via `\FA`) seemed appropriate.

Comment: Thank you, it works!
The only one problem now is the size of list bullets. With `\fontsize{5}{5}` bullets are ok, but icons too small; with `\fontsize{10}{10}` — icons are good, but bullets too big: https://i.imgur.com/mhRwV0P.png

Comment: @Stas: Try using `\def\faCircleBlank{\raisebox{.4ex}{\scalebox{.6}{\FA\symbol{"F10C}}}}`.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [revision 147 of moderncv](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~xdanaux/moderncv/trunk/revision/147), I am using following workaround with version 1.5.1 of moderncv as included in TeXLive 2015: `\def\faCircleBlank{{\faCircleO}}`. Make sure to place that directly after `\documentclass`, before `\moderncvstyle` or similar!

Another solution would be to update to version 2.0.0 of moderncv.

Answer (score 0):

There are two errors: 1) that being the extra "}" as indicated; 2) a section that needed to be enclosed in the \cventry section; 3) the fontspec package is missing. The code here compiles properly.

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}
\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{blue}
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\moderncvicons{awesome}

\name{John}{Doe}
\title{R\'{e}sum\'{e} title} 
\phone[mobile]{+1~(234)~567~890}
\phone[fixed]{+2~(345)~678~901}
\phone[fax]{+3~(456)~789~012}
\email{john@doe.org}   
\homepage{www.johndoe.com} 
\social[linkedin]{john.doe} 
\social[twitter]{jdoe}      
\social[github]{jdoe}       



\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\section{Experience}
\subsection{Vocational}
\cventry{year--year}{Job title}{Employer}{City}{}{General description no longer than 1--2 lines.\newline{}%
Detailed achievements:}%
\begin{itemize}%
\item Achievement 1;
\item Achievement 2, with sub-achievements:
  \begin{itemize}%
  \item Sub-achievement (a);
  \item Sub-achievement (b), with sub-sub-achievements (don't do this!);
    \begin{itemize}
    \item Sub-sub-achievement i;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement ii;
    \item Sub-sub-achievement iii;
    \end{itemize}
  \item Sub-achievement (c);
  \end{itemize}
\item Achievement 3.
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

The code produces:
[image: Jdoe-resume]

Comment: The problem still persists.

Comment: @Werner it should be fixed now. The issue was that "\usepackage{fontawesome}" is required.

Comment: Could you provide your version of [`fontawesome`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontawesome)? CTAN reports it as 4.3.0-1, and that's with the latest update (mentioned in the OP).

Comment: @Leucippus, your code doesn't contains `\moderncvicons{awesome}`

Comment: @Stas fontspec package was missing and now \moderncvicons{awesome} works